# How to dynamically store a permanent value to a TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

I'm making an Android bank app with Java , this is the withdrawal function that i had problems with it.
[Main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ORt.jpg)

[The withdrawal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVRnt.jpg)

When i choose 100 or any option the value is deducted from the balance the problem here is that the balance is a TextView i am using `setText()` to update the balance but when the page is refreshed or goes from activity to activity it doesn't stored permanently, it's not dynamically  saved so what's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Shared Preferences` to save value permanently
create a SharedPreference like this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
        "amount_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Write your value to it on your button onClicks or whatever way change the value like this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
//This will put value to sharedpreference with id amount_key
// like this new value can be 100 less than previous one
editor.putInt("amount_key", newValueToPutThereInText);
editor.apply();
```

This will save the `newValueToPutThereInText` to SharedPreference permanently.

and to access that value use this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int amount = sharedPref.getInt("amount_key", anyDefaultValueToUse);
// and use it in your balance textview
Textview balance = findViewById(R.id.your_id);
balance.setText(amount);
```

See [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Comment: lx There is no such a method like getActivity in the SharedPreferences class! what are we using it for?

Comment: for the Context , no it's not the part of `Shared Preferences` , are you getting any error??